# How to use RGB codes with the fmt library?

Tags: c++, c++20, rgb, fmt

I just installed the [fmt library](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html) and I was wondering if it is possible to use RGB codes instead of color names. For example, instead of,

```cpp
#include <fmt/color.h>

int main()
{
    std::string cpp = fmt::format(fg(fmt::color::yellow), "C++20");
    fmt::print("{}", cpp);
    return 0;
}
```

would it be possible to do something like,

```cpp
#include <fmt/color.h>

int main()
{
    std::string cpp = fmt::format(fg(fmt::color::#FFFF00), "C++20");
    fmt::print("{}", cpp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fmt::color::#FFFF00` is not valid C++ syntax because of the `#`.  Did you try `fmt::rgb(0xFFFF00)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of searching the internet, I stumbled upon the answer using the trial and error approach. In order to use RGB codes instead of color names, replace `color::yellow` with `rgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00)` or `rgb(255, 255, 0)`.

```cpp
#include <fmt/color.h>

int main()
{
    std::string cpp = fmt::format(fg(fmt::rgb(255, 255, 0)), "C++20");
    fmt::print("{}", cpp);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT** ‒ Thanks to **Wyck** for the awesome suggestion in the comment.

I just discovered that the following examples also work and are 100% syntactically valid:

```cpp
#include <fmt/color.h>

int main()
{
    std::string cpp = fmt::format(fg(fmt::rgb(0xFFFF00)), "C++20");
    fmt::print("{}", cpp);
    return 0;
}
```

and

```cpp
#include <fmt/color.h>

int main()
{
    std::string cpp = fmt::format(fg(fmt::color(0xFFFF00)), "C++20");
    fmt::print("{}", cpp);
    return 0;
}
```

All examples in this answer have been tested and are working.